# Heavy asterisk (u2731) in Android 2.x

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

I need Heavy asterisk (u2731) character in my app.
For android 3 and later I used the the following in my TextView:

```
android:text="\u2731"
```

and it works fine. But in android 2.x I see a rectangle instead of asterisk. I think that the specific Unicode character is missing in default fonts of Android 2.x .
So what can I do to see this character in Android 2.x? May be I need to load a custom font?
Which font contains this character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Android 3.0 uses the **Roboto** font.
You can easily find it for free as a ttf font you might want to store in your assets folder.

Here is the reference and downlad [site](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html)

**[EDIT]**

A workaround could be something like this:

```
String str = "your string containing fat asterisks (**)";
str = str.replace("**", "<b>*</b>");
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

It will make all the ** occurrences become a BOLD *

Comment: When I load roboto and set it as the typefase of the textview, in Android 4.x I still see the Heavy asterisk, so ther is "\u2731" code in the font, but now in Android 2.x I don't see even the rectangle, it is just blank...

Comment: So, it appears to be a limit of Android 2.x. Can you use a BOLD attribute on that character (or even play with size), to make it appear fatter?

Comment: Yes, it can do may work but I think it is a dirty way... I will use this way if I will not find any other. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, a dirty way is better than no way at all... ;)

Comment: Of course it is better then no way. Thank you for you answer! So I did the following: I checked if Android version is lover than Honeycomb and if it is, I did what you have suggested. For other versions, it will be clean )

Comment: It's a good compromise - I think it should be done this way. After all, 2.x devices are becoming a rarity.